# How to get a look up table to return a string rather than [object Object]

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert dna sequence to rna. When the sequence is passed in to my method I use a regex to get each indivdual letter and then use a look up table to convert each letter.

I'm trying to get a string value returned but the values that are being returned as `[object Object]`. I understand that the return value is of type `object` and I'm wondering is there a way of preventing it from or converting it back to type `string`.

```
const traslateDna = {
  'G':'C',
  'C':'G',
  'T':'A',
  'A':'U'
}
export const toRna = (dna) => {
  let rna = dna.replace(/[A-Z]/g, traslateDna)  
  return rna;
};
```

String passed in:

```
"ACGTGTA"
```

Expected result:

```
"UGCACAU"
```

Comment: `replace()` expects a string or function as second parameter. You should probably use a function to 'translate' your dna string. [More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: This was helpful thank combined with Sajeeb Ahamed answer. I passed translateDna into an anonymous function `(char => tanslateDna[char])` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `regex` for this purpose. You can gain your result using simple [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const traslateDna = {
  'G':'C',
  'C':'G',
  'T':'A',
  'A':'U'
}

const toRna = (dna) => {
    return dna.split('').map(char => traslateDna[char]).join('');
}

const DnaSeq = "ACGTGTA";
const RnaSeq = toRna(DnaSeq);

console.log(RnaSeq);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. It opened my eyes to what was missing. I used both my code and yours although yours worked flawlessly. I passed `(char => traslateDna[char])`  into my `replace` method. I've been trying to use string translation rather than converting to an array to help learn aspects of Js.

Answer (score 2):

You can use spread syntax and reduce to get the desired output.

... will split the string and will create an array and use the element of this array as key to retrieve value from the object

```js
const traslateDna = {
  'G': 'C',
  'C': 'G',
  'T': 'A',
  'A': 'U'
}

function getRNA(str) {

  return [...str].reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc += traslateDna[curr]
    return acc;
  }, '')
}

console.log(getRNA("ACGTGTA"))
```

Comment: Your answer is great.